# How do i prove the existence of reals satisfying this inequality?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a_1,...,a_n$ be positive reals.

How do i prove that:

For any $\epsilon>0$, there exists positive reals $x_1,...,x_n$ such that $\prod_{i=1}^n (a_i + x_i) - \prod_{i=1}^n a_i ≦ \epsilon$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

You could try induction on $n$.

For the base case, $n=1$, you can just choose $x_1=\epsilon$.

If you know the result works for $n$, suppose we have $a_1,\ldots,a_{n+1}$. Then
$$
\begin{align*}
\prod_{i=1}^{n+1}(a_i+x_i)-\prod_{i=1}^{n+1}a_i&=(a_{n+1}+x_{n+1})\prod_{i=1}^{n}(a_i+x_i)-a_{n+1}\prod_{i=1}^{n}a_i\\
&=a_{n+1}\left[\prod_{i=1}^{n}(a_i+x_i)-\prod_{i=1}^{n}a_i\right]+x_{n+1}\prod_{i=1}^{n}(a_i+x_i).
\end{align*}
$$
Can you see, from here, how to choose $x_1,\ldots,x_n$, and then use that to determine $x_{n+1}$?

Comment: Thank you. Right after i posted my question, i realized this is just the intermediate value theorem to a function $f(x)=\prod_{i=1}^n (a_i + x) - \prod_{i=1}^n a_i$

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but for fixed $a_1, \ldots, a_n$,

$ \prod_{i=1}^n (a_i+t) - \prod_{i=1}^n a_i$ is a continuous function of $t$, and equals $0$ if $t=0$.  Suppose $\epsilon > 0$.  For small enough $|t|$,

$$ \prod_{i=1}^n (a_i+t) - \prod_{i=1}^n a_i < \epsilon.$$

Now just set $x_1 = x_2 = \cdots x_n = t$, where $t$ is chosen to be positive and small enough as described above.